# If statement being skipped, even though the values match

Tags: kotlin

Why is my if statement here being skipped? Directly to else:

```
override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        runOnUiThread {
            val xAxis = event.values[0]
            val yAxis = event.values[1]
            val zAxis = event.values[2]
            Log.d("Eixos", /*"Eixo X: $xAxis, Eixo Y: $yAxis,*/ "Eixo Z: $zAxis")
            if (zAxis in 0.900000..-0.900000){
                imagemCelular!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.phoneright)
                Log.d("Phonin", "Certo")
            }else{
                imagemCelular!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.phonewrong)
                Log.d("Phonin", "Errado")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a pic of the compiler, the value is indeed between what I need, but it's like my if statement is not even there.

[PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndkjR.png)

Answer (score 3):

By defining the range from large to small, Kotlin will assume this range is empty. If you flip the range around so it goes smallest to largest, this should work:

Change:

```
if (zAxis in 0.900000..-0.900000)
```

To:

```
if (zAxis in -0.900000..0.900000)
```

Or:

```
if (zAxis in -0.9..0.9){
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple. Jeez, how did I miss that?

Comment: It happens! I've made the same mistake. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you must change position between 0.9 and -0.9 because operator function define is

```
override fun contains(value: T): Boolean = lessThanOrEquals(start, value) && lessThanOrEquals(value, endInclusive)
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Feeling very stoopid right now.